How to Customize "Regenerate Inventory Planning" to Retrieve Only Sales Orders with "open" Status in Acumatica?
"Regenerate Inventory Planning" to Retrieve Only Sales Orders with "open" Status in Acumatica?
I am working on customizing the Regenerate Inventory Planning process in Acumatica. By default, this process retrieves all sales orders, but I need to modify it to filter only those with open status


What have you tried so far? what status are you trying to not include? there is an option to exclude orders on hold. This process looks at the same data set as found in Inventory Allocation Details. You might need to add your own logic into MRPEngine to delete or mark rows as processed in AMRPDetailFP data.
